# AWS Beanstalk deploy across multiple AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm in the process of setting up multiple AWS accounts. The plan is to create separate accounts for each environment - DEV, QA , UAT & PROD.

Our web application is hosted using elastic beanstalk. The CI/CD pipeline will tag and deploy a version to beanstalk application in DEV account for each commit - This is working great.

We are tying to figure out how to deploy a chosen tagged version to different AWS account (QA), we will have a beanstalk application created with same name in QA as well.

I'm looking for a better way to manage the releases, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Named Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-profile) to target different accounts. The syntax might look something like `eb deploy --profile qa myapp-env-qa`.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Any thoughts on how to initiate this from a web interface? eg: dev ops person can choose 'deploy to QA', 'deploy to UAT' etc.,?

Comment: You didn't specify what CI/CD system you're using, but somewhere under the covers it has to be executing `eb deploy`. Once you find where that is happening, you should be able to pass the appropriate flags.